# EF Code First - Primary Key Data Type Change

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

We need to change one of our tables to use a `Guid` as the primary key rather than an `int`.  This system is in use in production and it appears that this change requires some additional work rather than the usual `add-migration` stuff.

There are two FK references to this table meaning that there are 3 total tables needing to be modified.

How should this be handled when using Code First?

#### CURRENT MODEL CODE

```
public class TableA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

#### DESIRED MODEL CODE

```
public class TableA
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First do the change on the code and then install or host your application and create the fresh database out of the new changes.  Now you have the database with the new changes. So make a diff between the one in production ( after backing it up and import it in your test server) and the fresh one ( with the new change), now you can create your upgrade script from the diff for the production. Then first upgrade the database of production and then publish your app

Comment: Thanks for supplying this...  I really wish this could be handled more gracefully...